# How to modify the properties of a SQL Server Analysis Services database field in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, azure-analysis-services

I am working with Power BI on a model that is a cube of a SQL Server Analysis Services database.

When I go to the model view and select a field from a table in my model, I would like to be able to modify these properties but the fields remain grayed out as in the picture below :
[image]

When I want to use Power Query I get this error message, what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the way you are connected. You are connecting to SSAS rather than building a model yourself, so any modifications would have to be done to the SSAS rather than locally.

Fortunately, there have been [recent updates](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/directquery-for-power-bi-datasets-and-azure-analysis-services-preview/) that allow you to change the connection type to a DirectQuery which allows for local modeling. It's still pretty new, so there are still some limitations and rough edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes this is what I wanted to do using DirectQuery.
If I open my model in an empty Power BI file I can then modify it with DirectQuery. 
But if I open my old .pbi file with my reports built in it and then open the SSAS model it works but when I want to have the model locally and make the modifications with DirectQuery I get the message "Assign these measurements to a home table: Target" and I don't understand what that means...

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?